# Left arrow on EditTexts crashes application

Tags: android, android-edittext

On one of my Activities I have several EditTexts.  If you run my application on the emulator, select one of these EditTexts and press the left arrow key on your hardware keyboard, the application will crash.

I'm not really sure why.  All EditTexts on all of my other Activities do not cause this issue.  As far as I can tell, I'm not doing anything strange with the EditTexts on this screen.  I do not override handlers such as onKey.  Really, I do nothing with them except when the user leaves the screen, and then I just grab the text.

Any ideas?

Here is the error output:

```
03-07 11:08:09.781: E/AndroidRuntime(388): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: -2 < 0
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.charAt(SpannableStringBuilder.java:110)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.text.TextUtils.getCapsMode(TextUtils.java:1573)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.getCursorCapsMode(BaseInputConnection.java:273)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:4482)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:942)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1114)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.isActive(InputMethodManager.java:539)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4011)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6641)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-07 11:08:09.811: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Again, I have no code traversing the text or dealing with indices.  I override no handlers.  I simply call findViewById when the Activity starts and grab the text out of the EditText when the Activity ends.

Comment: Maybe a bug in the emulator? if it won't show up on actual device (and it won't because devices don't have arrows) why even bother? :P probably a bug in the emulator itself. Those emulators really are peace of junk.

Comment: oh and by the way, it actually is a bug. it's trying to go left when standing on zero index. that's why an IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is known bug on emulator. here is a [link to issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5164)